# Characterization of Galois Group of $\overline{{\bf F}}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

**Fact** : Galois Group $G$ of $\overline{{\bf F}}_p$ is $\hat{{\bf Z}}$

This is a fact. I want to prove this. And I do not know the definition of $\hat{{\bf Z}}$

Here ${\bf F}_p$ is a finite field which contains $p$ elements and $p$ is a prime.

**Definitions** :  And let ${\bf F}_{p^k}$ is a splitting field for $x^{p^k}-x\in {\bf F}_p[x]$. And $\overline{{\bf F}}_p = \bigcup_{k\geq 1} {\bf F}_{p^k}$ is an algebraically closed field. Note that Galois group for ${\bf F}_{p^k}$ is a cyclic ${\bf Z}_k=\langle \sigma_k\rangle$ whose generator is $\sigma_k : x\mapsto x^p$, called by $Frobenius$.

**Try** : And there exists some property : $$ {\bf F}_{p^k}\subset {\bf F}_{p^n}\Leftrightarrow  k|n$$

Hence for $\sigma_q : {\bf F}_{p^q}\rightarrow {\bf F}_{p^q}$ where $q$ is a prime, we have an extension $\overline{\sigma}_q\in G$ which is generator of 
${\bf F}_{p^{qn}}\rightarrow {\bf F}_{p^{qn}}$ for all $n$.

Henece since $n$ may be any prime, $G$ is cyclic group which is isomorphic to ${\bf Z}$.

Am I right ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the absolute Galois group $G=\textrm{Gal}\bigl(\overline{\mathbb F}_p/\mathbb F_p\bigr)$ is not $\mathbb Z$.
To find what it is, use the following facts:

1. $\textrm{Gal}(\mathbb F_{p^n}/\mathbb F_p)$ is the cyclic group of order $n$ (this you already know).
2. $G=\varprojlim \textrm{Gal}(\mathbb F_{p^n}/\mathbb F_p)$ (Galois theory for infinite extensions).

The above should say that $$G=\varprojlim \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z=\widehat{\mathbb Z},$$ the [profinite completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_group)
of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you. In some case, ${\rm Gal}\ ({\bf F}_{p^{qm}}/{\bf F}_p)={\bf Z}_{q^m}$ where $q$ is prime. So $\bigcup_{m\geq 1}{\bf F}_{p^{qm}}$ has Galois group which is inverse limit of ${\bf Z}_{q^m}$, that is, $q$-adic integer.